# How to add content type as a menu item child without displaying the link in the menu?

Tags: uri, blocks, routes

I recently found menu block module, which displays my submenu very nicely. Here's the menu hierarchy:

```
Home
About
News & events
-- News
-- Events
Contact
```

So when I go to the News & events page and from there to the News page the submenu displays just fine. But when I open a piece of news in the News page (which is a view displaying content from the News content type) the sub menu disappears. I'd like to show the submenu like the piece of news I just opened would be a child of News menu item. The problem is how to this without actually displaying all the news links in the menu. I know that there's a way to disable menu links but haven't found a way to disable them by default when adding new content.

What would be the best way to implement this kind of hierarchy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your path aliases are something like, e.g., example.com/news/node_alias, you could use the [menu trail by path](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path) module. That way, you don't have to add the nodes to the menu to achieve this: the News item remains active on subpaths of /news/*.